# Flutter responsive design for container height and width, fontsize of text, padding, margin, etc

Tags: android, flutter, dart, responsive

What is the best approach/ best practice to design a responsive Flutter app? Like the width and height of a container, fontSize of a text that is responsive to different size of device.

I have tried like

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
Text(
    "Dummy Text",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: size.height * 0.03),
)
```

but it just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

It is very broad question, i'll try to answer based on my knowledge.

There are several ways in which you can achieve responsiveness.

1.**`Extended`, `Flexible`,`AspectRatio`**

> By using `screen-responsive` layout widgets like `Extended`, `Flexible`, and `AspectRatio`. Your UI can adapt to various screen sizes and orientations with the aid of these widgets.

2.**`MediaQuery`**

> To determine the device screen size and modify your UI components accordingly, you can use `MediaQuery`. To obtain the device's screen dimensions, you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.`

3.**`LayoutBuilder`**

> To modify your UI elements in accordance with the limitations offered by its parent widget, you can use the `LayoutBuilder` widget. It is based on the principle as its restrictions change, this widget rebuilds its child widget.

4.**`FittedBox`**

> To automatically resize your UI components to fit within their parent container, you can take aid of `FittedBox` widget.

5.**`AspectRatio`**

> To specify a certain aspect ratio that the widget should have on the screen, use the `AspectRatio` widget.

Example:

```
Text(
  'Dummy Text',
  style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   ),
);
```

In this example, the `fontSize` is set to `5%` of the width of the device's screen.